# NA in list considered numeric. How to convert to NA object?

Tags: r

I have a vector that I am attempting to replace values in using if/else. It replaces all values except NA. Can someone tell me why?

My suspicion is that the NA are being treated as numbers (based on checking the class of the NA list value which returns numeric) but if they are being treated that way how can I get R to see them as NA objects so my if statement works?

```
> V(g)$label
  [1] 13  9 17 34  8 15  0 10 19 21  9 12 23 12 19 25 12 23 20 13 35  1  3  0  0 34 42 10 26 24 17 21 14  0  0  5  8 25  1 38 21  7 28  1  7  5  2  0 33  9  0  3 24  8 28 31  1  4 12 42 18 14 22 44  7 20 17 25 16 20 15
 [72]  8 13 45  8 32 13 25 15 33 15 13 52 37  2  4 27 41 12 33 26  4  0  7 37 43 24 23 22  9  3  7  8 13 20  0  0  0  9 10  1  2 18 16  0  0  8 11  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> class(V(g)$label[130])
[1] "numeric"
> V(g)$label[130]
[1] NA

########converts values

V(g)$label <- ifelse(as.numeric(V(g)$label) < 10, 1, 
                ifelse(as.numeric(V(g)$label) >= 30, 3, 
                ifelse(is.na(V(g)$label),999,2)))
> V(g)$label
  [1]  2  1  2  3  1  2  1  2  2  2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  1  1  1  1  3  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  3  2  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  1  2  1  2  3  1  1  2  3  2  2  2  3  1  2  2  2  2  2  2
 [72]  1  2  3  1  3  2  2  2  3  2  2  3  3  1  1  2  3  2  3  2  1  1  1  3  3  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  2  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Could you please add the result of `dput(V(g)$label)` and also add the desired result.  I suspect there's a better way to arrive at your desired result. The NA values are classed as numeric because they are in a numeric vector to begin with.  They are not actually being treated as numbers.

Comment: You can also change the NA values first using `is.na(V(g)$label) <- 999` and things would probably go more smoothly

Comment: Instead of using several `ifelse`, you may consider `cut` with appropriate `breaks`, and then replace `NA` in a last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `NA` first. This should work:

```
V(g)$label <- ifelse(is.na(V(g)$label), 999, 
                     ifelse(as.numeric(V(g)$label) < 10, 1, 
                     ifelse(as.numeric(V(g)$label) >= 30, 3, 2)))
```

Comment: So the if else checks the first value, finds the condition it fits then checks the next value? Arrrgh that code looks like it would check each condition sequentially

Comment: @Rilcon42, yes, the conditions are evaluated sequentially starting at the outermost `ifelse` towards the inner `ifelse` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is not going to keep checking the other conditions once the first condition (whether the value is less than 10) evaluates to `NA`, because `NA` is not the same as `FALSE`. If you are somehow averse to checking for `NA` as the first condition, you can add it in stealthily to make your computer do more work:

```
V(g)$label <- 
    ifelse(V(g)$label < 10  & is.na(V(g)$label)==FALSE, 1, 
        ifelse(V(g)$label >= 30  & is.na(V(g)$label)==FALSE, 3, 
            ifelse(is.na(V(g)$label),999,2)))
```

But I do not know why would would want to check the same condition three times.